# why is my method not returning a value when called?

Tags: c#, class, methods

I'm trying to create a program that takes user input and passes it to three methods.

- one method calculates total pay
- one method determines shift selected
- I want the last method to be the display method, but I've used a method that receives parameters to pass the information, a `void` method, and `static` which caused more problems than it helped.

Why is the method not getting the information?

This class has its own code file called Employee.

Class method to display results:

```cs
//Method to display results
public void Display(double total)
{
    //main form instance to access controls
    MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();

    mainForm.nameSumBox  .Text = Name;
    mainForm.empNumSumBox.Text = EmployeeNumber.ToString();
    mainForm.paySumBox   .Text = total.ToString();
    mainForm.shiftSumBox .Text = SelectedShift;
}
```

Call-site:

```
try
{
    //variables
    double totalPay;

    //get user entry
    employee.Name = nameBox.Text;
    employee.EmployeeNumber = int.Parse(empNumBox.Text);
    employee.HRPay = double.Parse(hrPayBox.Text);
    employee.SelectedShift = employee.ShiftChoice(); // method to determine shift selection

    //calculate pay total
    totalPay = employee.CalcPay();

    //display
    employee.Display(totalPay);
```

Comment: `int.Parse(empNumBox.Text);` <-- This will throw an exception if your `empNumBox.Text` does not contain a `CurrentCulture`-parsable integer value, such as if the textbox is empty. How do you intend for form-validation to work and implement error-handling?

Comment: I'm using a try catch statement around my calculateBtn event to handle any exceptions thrown by the methods when they're called

Comment: Se this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74247610/sending-control-to-another-form#comment131085549_74247610 - you don't want create a new form.

Comment: I thought when you create a Class File in Visual that it isn't a separate form?

Comment: `new MainForm();` will always create a new form. Instead pass the mainform as parameter to the funcion and use that.

Comment: Like `public void Display(MainForm mainForm, double total)`.

Comment: Poul Bak gave the solution. The reason why the value is not return is because you assign it to the local `mainForm` which is lost when exiting the function.

Answer (score 0):

When using Poul's solution, It was a success!

for the main file when calling the method:
`employee.Display(this, totalPay);`

Answer (score 0):

Display Method should be

```
public void Display(MainForm mainForm, double total)
{
    mainForm.nameSumBox.Text = Name;
    mainForm.empNumSumBox.Text = EmployeeNumber.ToString();
    mainForm.paySumBox.Text = total.ToString();
    mainForm.shiftSumBox.Text = SelectedShift;
}
```

*pass the mainform as parameter to the funcion.*